# How can I Insert JSON object into Postgres using Java preparedStatement?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, prepared-statement

I’m struggling to insert a JSON object into my postgres v9.4 DB.  I have defined the column called "evtjson" as type `json`  (not `jsonb`).

I am trying to use a prepared statement in Java (jdk1.8) to insert a Json object (built using JEE javax.json libraries) into the column, but I keep running into SQLException errors.

I create the JSON object using:

```
JsonObject mbrLogRec = Json.createObjectBuilder().build();
…
mbrLogRec = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("New MbrID", newId)
                .build();
```

Then I pass this object as a parameter to another method to write it to the DB using a prepared statement. (along with several other fields)   As:

```
pStmt.setObject(11, dtlRec);
```

Using this method, I receive the following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No hstore extension installed.
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setMap(PgPreparedStatement.java:553)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setObject(PgPreparedStatement.java:1036)

I have also tried:

```
pStmt.setString(11, dtlRec.toString());
pStmt.setObject(11, dtlRec.toString());
```

Which produce a different error:

> Event JSON:  {"New MbrID":29}
>
> SQLException: ERROR: column "evtjson" is of type json but expression is of type character varying
>
> Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

But, at least this tells me that the DB is recognizing the column as type JSON.
I did try installing the hstore extension, but it then told me that it was not an hstore object.

OracleDocs shows a number of various methods to set the parameter value in the preparedStatement, but I'd rather not try them all if someone knows the answer. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) These also reference an additional parameter, SQLType, but I can't find any reference to these.

Should I try `setAsciiStream`? `CharacterStream`? CLOB?

Answer (score 93):

This behaviour is quite annoying since JSON strings are accepted without problems when used as literal strings in SQL commands.

There is a already an [issue](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/265) for this in the postgres driver Github repository (even if the problem seems the be the serverside processing).

Besides using a cast (see answer of 
@a_horse_with_no_name) in the sql string, the issue author offers two additional solutions:

1. Use a parameter `stringtype=unspecified` in the JDBC connection URL/options.

> This tells PostgreSQL that all text or varchar parameters are actually
>   of unknown type, letting it infer their types more freely.

2. Wrap the parameter in a `org.postgresql.util.PGobject`:

```
 PGobject jsonObject = new PGobject();
 jsonObject.setType("json");
 jsonObject.setValue(yourJsonString);
 pstmt.setObject(11, jsonObject);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think option 2 is more what I was looking for.  If I understand the code correctly, this is more in line with using JSON in the way that postgres intends.  However, isn't this including another conversion step from a javax.json object to a string to wrap it in a PG JSON object? (option 2, step 3)  It seems like using JSON objects in general is a waste and I'm better off sticking with string manipulation for now.  Would I be correct in assuming that option 1 would have broader performance impacts because then the JDBC driver would have to do a lot of inferring?

Comment: @MaybeWeAreAllRobots regarding performance: you should try, it might not be noticeable.

Comment: @wero, you are not wero, you are hero!

Comment: pStmt.setObject(11, dtlRec.toString(), java.sql.Types.OTHER); Also works (as mentioned in the link you provided).

Answer (score 50):

You can do it like this and you just need the json string:

Change the query to:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO table (json_field) VALUES (to_json(?::json))"
```

And set the parameter as a String.

```
pStmt.setString(1, json);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Using `pStmt.setString(1, json);` caused an error in eclipse, but changing it to `pStmt.setString(1, json.toString());` worked!
Some follow-ups:  What is the difference between using: `to_json(?::json)` and `cast(? as json)` ?  Also, is the net result that I'm stuffing text into a JSON object, then converting it back to text for the JDBC driver, then having the DB reconvert it back to JSON, so that the DB can store it as text??  Am I understanding this correctly? And, if so, shouldn't I just keep it all as a string field and text column?

Comment: to_json(?::json) converts a String to valid json, check the docs [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html):

cast(? as json) seems to just cast the parameter as JSON, docs  [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createcast.html).

The advantages is that you can [query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype) the JSON field directly which you couldn't in a String field, also it enforces a structure, makes sure it's a valid JSON and I believe you can enforce certain fields.

Comment: Also PGObject aproach also works from the other response I can't comment on yet, but if you are using something like wildfly (what I use) You might get into trouble: I made this question myself a few months back [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441201/inserting-postgres-json-column-using-wildfly) in case you are interested.

Comment: Awesome answer! Works very well when dealing with 3rd party access to the SQL DB. Ran into this issue while working with Mirth Connect.

Comment: why do you need the `to_json()` part?! `VALUES (?::json)` works just fine

Comment: How to implement same thing using JPA?

Answer (score 25):

You have two options:

1. Use statement.setString(jsonStr) and then handle the conversion in the sql statement:

   ```java
   PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(
     "insert into table (jsonColumn) values (?::json)");
   statement.setString(1, jsonStr);
   ```
2. Another option is to use PGobject to create a custom value wrapper.

   ```java
   PGobject jsonObject = new PGobject();
   PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(
     "insert into table (jsonColumn) values (?)");
   jsonObject.setType("json");
   jsonObject.setValue(jsonStr);
   statement.setObject(1, jsonObject);
   ```

I personally prefer the latter as the query is cleaner

Comment: Good point but option #1 is also quite clean, plus: it does not introduce compile time dependency on postgres

Comment: I initially used #2, but then when I wanted to write integration tests in Spring using a H2 database, PgObject does not play nice with H2. So switched to option #1. Upon switching and executing the integration test, h2 does not like the syntax `?::json` (it instead needs the format `? FORMAT JSON`, so I had to extract the insert string as a spring property, using "insert into table (jsonColumn) values (?::json)" for regular runs, and "insert into table (jsonColumn) values (? FORMAT JSON)" for the Spring "test" profile.

Answer (score 18):

Passing the JSON as a String is the right approach, but as the error message tells you, you need to cast the *parameter* in the `INSERT` statement to a `JSON` value:

```
insert into the_table
   (.., evtjson, ..) 
values 
   (.., cast(? as json), ..)
```

Then you can use `pStmt.setString(11, dtlRec.toString())` to pass the value

Answer (score 9):

Most answers here defines ways of inserting into postgres json field with jdbc in a non-standard way, ie. it is db implementation specific. If you need to insert a java string into a postgres json field with pure jdbc and pure sql use:

```
preparedStatement.setObject(1, "{}", java.sql.Types.OTHER)
```

This will make the postgres jdbc driver (tested with org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.19) convert the java string to the json type. It will also validate the string as being a valid json representation, something that various answers using implicit string casts does not do - resulting in the possibility of corrupt persisted json data.

Comment: This should be for sure the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, your SQL string needs to explicitly cast the bind value to the PostgreSQL `json` or `jsonb` type:

```sql
insert into t (id, j) values (?, ?::json)
```

Now you can bind the string value. Alternatively, you can use a library that can do it, for example [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) (works out of the box) or [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/) (using a third party `UserType` registration). The benefits of this is that you don't have to think about this every time you bind such a variable (or read it). A jOOQ example:

```java
ctx.insertInto(T)
   .columns(T.ID, T.J)
   .values(1, JSON.valueOf("[1, 2, 3]"))
   .execute();
```

Behind the scenes, the same cast as above is always generated, whenever you work with this [`JSON`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/JSON.html) (or [`JSONB`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/JSONB.html)) data type.

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)

Answer (score -1):

if using spring boot: adding the following line to application.properties helped:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.stringtype=unspecified
```

as Wero wrote:

> This tells PostgreSQL that all text or varchar parameters are actually
>   of unknown type

Answer (score -3):

Instead of passing json object pass its string value and cast it to json in the query.
Example:

```
JSONObject someJsonObject=..........

String yourJsonString = someJsonObject.toString();

String query = "INSERT INTO table (json_field) VALUES (to_json(yourJsonString::json))";
```

this worked for me.

Comment: This is a good example of **SQL-injection as a feature**. Please, avoid this (or any similar) solution at all costs!