# How to insert JSON into Postgres via java?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, insert-into

I have created a table books in PostgreSql.

```
CREATE TABLE books ( id integer, data json );
```

My Json:

```
 { "name": "Book the First", "author": { "first_name": "Bob", "last_name": "White" } }
```

How can i insert json into Postgres via java code?

Comment: Run an `insert` using a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Hope this will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844138/how-can-i-insert-json-object-into-postgres-using-java-preparedstatement

Answer (score 7):

Thank you :).This really helped me to resolve the issue.

```
String json = "{ \"name\": \"Book the First\", \"author\": { \"first_name\": \"Priya\", \"last_name\": \"White\" } }";
         PGobject jsonObject = new PGobject();
         jsonObject.setType("json");
         jsonObject.setValue(json);
         PreparedStatement stmt=c.prepareStatement("insert into books values(2,?)");
         stmt.setObject(1, jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another one doubt.How to split JSON key value pair and insert into postgreSql table's column.

For example my JSON looks like
{
"Name":"xyz"
"salary":10000
}

I want to insert into separate columns Name and salary in Postgres.

Comment: You must parse the json string

Comment: Still having doubts on this.how to split JSON using parser?can you pls explain it

Comment: The process will depend on the parser you choose