# How can I insert JSON data into Postgres JSON data type column using JAVA

Tags: java, postgresql

How can I insert JSON data into Postgres JSON data type column using JAVA.

I am having a JSON which I need to save in Postgres database in JSON type column.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844138/how-can-i-insert-json-object-into-postgres-using-java-preparedstatement