# Mapping Json type from Postgresql in Scala code

Tags: json, postgresql, scala

I have the table with `json` data type in `Postgresql` and i must choice the eligible mapping of this field in Scala code for case class field (i don't use `slick` where i can directly set something like `sql.json`). I consider the next variants:

1. `java.lang.Object` with following validation.
2. `play.libs.Json` or `io.circe.Json`

But i can't choice one of them and I don't other possible candidate for this place.

**UPD** For interacting with DB i use quill

Comment: So... what do you use for interacting with your database ? The answer will heavily depend on that.

Comment: @Sarvesh Kumar Singh  i use quill for interacting with DB;

Comment: Look at the http://getquill.io/#extending-quill-custom-encoding section. Incase of json you can use any Json library you want. Just provide an appropriate codec to interface with underlying `java.sql.Types.OTHER`.

Answer (score 1):

As Sarvesh mentioned it, it highly depends on the library you are going to use. There is a nice pg-slick extension (https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) that supports most of the json libraries.

As for the other libraries, I did not find any relevant resource. It is however possible to insert json with plain SQL. Find resource [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844138/how-can-i-insert-json-object-into-postgres-using-java-preparedstatement)