# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "tags" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, mybatis

After I changed the PostgreSQL 13 database columns `tags` to jsonb, throw error when execute sql:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "tags" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 519
### The error may exist in class path resource [mybatis/mapper/dolphin/RssSubSourceMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.dolphin.soa.post.dao.RssSubSourceMapper.updateByPrimaryKeySelective-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: UPDATE rss_sub_source SET sub_url = ?, created_time = ?, updated_time = ?, sub_status = ?, rss_type = ?, standard_type = ?, standard_version = ?, cron = ?, trigger_count = ?, next_trigger_time = ?, sub_name = ?, last_trigger_time = ?, intro = ?, failed_count = ?, frequency_month = ?, reputation = ?, rep_latest_refresh_time = ?, scrapy_take_time = ?, censor_status = ?, etag = ?, last_modified = ?, editor_pick = ?, fav_icon_url = ?, dynamic_interval = ?, creator = ?, tags = ?, article_count = ?, article_count_latest_refresh_time = ?, comment_rss = ?, part_output = ? WHERE id = ?
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "tags" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 519
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "tags" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 519
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:239) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:91) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar!/:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:441) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar!/:2.0.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.update(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.update(SqlSessionTemplate.java:288) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar!/:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:67) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar!/:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:152) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar!/:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:85) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar!/:3.5.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.updateByPrimaryKeySelective(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

what should I do to handle the jsonb in spring boot application when using mybatis?

Comment: There are three options (at least). 1) use `jsonb` function : `tags = jsonb(#{tags})` 2) use cast `tags = #{tags}::JSONB` 3) use a type handler. For implementing 3), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35845278/1261766) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally add the `JsonTypeHandler` fixed this problem:

```
package misc.config.mybatis;

import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedTypes;
import org.postgresql.util.PGobject;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@MappedTypes({Object.class})
public class JsonTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<Object> {

    private Class<Object> clazz;

    public JsonTypeHandler(Class<Object> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public JsonTypeHandler() {
    }

    private static final PGobject jsonObject = new PGobject();

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Object parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        jsonObject.setType("json");
        jsonObject.setValue(JSON.toJSONString(parameter));
        ps.setObject(i, jsonObject);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return JSON.parseObject(rs.getString(columnName), clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return JSON.parseObject(rs.getString(columnIndex), clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return JSON.parseObject(cs.getString(columnIndex), clazz);
    }
}
```

in the mybatis mapper xml, specify the custom JsonTypeHandler like this:

```
<result column="tags" jdbcType="OTHER" property="tags" typeHandler="misc.config.mybatis.JsonTypeHandler" />
```

if using mybatis code auto generator, add code generator config like this:

```
    <table tableName="rss_sub_source"
           enableCountByExample="true"
           enableUpdateByExample="true"
           enableDeleteByExample="true"
           enableSelectByExample="true"
           selectByExampleQueryId="true">
        <generatedKey column="ID" sqlStatement="JDBC" identity="true" />
        <columnOverride column="tags" jdbcType="OTHER" typeHandler="misc.config.mybatis.JsonTypeHandler"/>
    </table>
```